# Truss with multiple unknowns?

Tags: geometry

[image]

So ive got the moments of :

B:
Vertical : sin(75)AB + sin(45)BC = 33lbs
Horizontal : cos(75)AB = DB + cos(45)BC

D:
Vertical: sin(60)DC + sin(65)DE = 100lbs
Horizontal: cos(60)DC + BD = cos(65)DE

A:
Vertical: wf = sin(75)AB
Horizontal: cos(75)AB

E: 
Vertical: wb = sin(65)DE
Horizontal: CE = cos(65)DE

How do i solve this truss problem with multiple unknowns? It seems every possible manipulation leaves me with atleast one unknown.

Comment: Well you can get another equation by noting that the total sum of forces on the entire object has to be zero (since the truss is not moving). So you would also have: $w_f+w_b= 100+33=133$.

Comment: So would i be correct in assuming that sin(75)AB + sin(65)DE = 133, and cos(64)DE = cos(75)AB, since wf + wb = 133?